# I deleted my web.config, how to recreate?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a simple way to recreate my accidently deleted web.config file from Visual Studio?

Comment: if not source control, recycle bin? ;)

Comment: do I look like I use source control?

Comment: Looks don't matter, but you sound like you could use source control.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll lose all your custom settings, but...

Right Click on your Project -> Add Item... -> Select 'Web Configuration File' (name it web.config)

In the future, you might want to use some form of Source Control ([Git](http://git-scm.com/) would be good for a single developer that doesn't want to worry about setting up a Source Control server).

Comment: +1 for source control and mentioning that she will lose all of the custom settings in this file, like encrypted database connections strings, http handlers, app settings, etc. if there were any.

Answer (score 1):

I went to the Recycle Bin and luckily was able to restore my Web.config that I accidently deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you just recently created the project, you could just create a new project, copy the file into your original project folder, then open it and perform a search and replace to ensure the namespace and other project-specific info correspond to your original project.

Of course, you could restore from the backup you remembered to make, right??  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are not using Source control.
If you can't restore your item you pretty much can't "recreate" your web.config. The settings you've created in this .config file are now just gone. If you make a new web.config file and your project wasn't very big yet you might be lucky. You might have a web.config local copy available somewhere, try a good search!